# What is the resulting RF power of the forward and reflected power if a Transmitter is operated into an open or short?

Tags: power-electronics, short-circuit, transmission

If I have a 25 Watt Transmitter that transmits through a switch into an open and/or short, what power would the switch experience assuming loss-less transmissions lines and switch?

Comment: what frequency and how long is the cable?

Comment: Btw incident power is forward power.

Comment: 2 GHz.  Sorry meant to say forward and reflected power.  Updated the question.

Comment: And the cable length?

Comment: Transmitter to switch is 2 ft, switch to short/open is 1 ft.

Answer (score 1):

You say the cable is 3 foot (about 1 metre) and the frequency is 3GHz (wavelength 0.1m). There could be ten "waves" along the length of the cable assuming the signal travelled at the speed of light.

There are probably more like 15 waves at 0.66 speed of light (about normal for cable). Depending on the exact length, the driving end of the cable could look like a short circuit or an open circuit or anywhere in between. It could look like that with or without a short circuit at the far end.

Take a look at this picture. It shows a cable driven by a signal and the cable is exactly one-quarter wavelength of the signal frequency. It looks like a short circuit: -

[image]

Same cable driven at twice the frequency looks like an open circuit because the cable length coincides with half a wavelength of the signal: -

[image]

For both scenarios above if you add cable to the existing piece (making it one wavelength longer) you get the same result: -

[image] and
[image]

Here's what happens when the cable is shorted: -

[image]

You get an open circuit at the sending end.

To prevent this answer getting too long, may I recommend you go to [this](http://isc.dcc.ttu.ee/Public/Kuphaldt/ac/AC_14.html) site where I borrowed the pictures from.

Answer (score 0):

The switch will "experience" up to 100 W of power. Let me explain:

If you have a large standing wave ratio from the open circuit, then the current and voltage magnitudes will vary down the length of the line.
At the current maxima, the current will be double the current for a matched circuit,  and,
At the voltage maxima, the voltage will be double that of a matched circuit.

The switch maximum power rating will be based on a maximum current it can handle without overheating, and/or a maximum voltage it can withstand without overheating or breakdown.

So given that you don't know the phase of the reflected signal very well, it's probably safe to assume the switch will experience a current or voltage equivalent to a matched power about 4 times larger. The same goes for the coax.

Note that unless you're using a fancy test amplifier, you can't assume it will produce full forward power into a mismatch load. It may cut its power back to protect its output stage.

Comment: Could you explain you you calculate the 100 Watts?

Comment: @ezolly3000 yes - increasing the power flowing in a transmission line by 4 times will double the voltage and current. 2*V * 2*I = 2*P.

Comment: @tomnexus, how does a 25W source produce 100W? What about conservation of energy? Without an antenna or terminating resistance there is zero power in the system.

Comment: @chu there is 25 W in the system, it travels out to the open circuit, is reflected back, and is absorbed by the transmitter. Switch and cable are lossless, assume transmitter matched. I didn't say there is 100 W anywhere, only that the switch and cable will "experience" voltages *or* currents equivalent to those of 100 W of normal forward power. So the switch and cable need to be rated for 100 W, 1:1 SWR, to withstand 25 W, high SWR. That's sort-of what he asked.

Comment: @tomnexus, 25W may be the power that the tx will deliver into a matched load, but that isn't the case for an open- or short-circuit transmission line. But I think the question 'what power would the switch experience' is rather meaningless. The switch will experience an RF voltage when it's open and an RF current when it's closed.